# MVVM: Binding changable Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have some sort of background task which executes periodically or if someone manually starts it.

Now I want some kind of Progress/Result View, which is showing the handled data. The window should be shown all the time.

The problem is, a new instance of the datamodel is created every time the background task starts. So how to keep the Binding of Model -> ViewModel even if the Model is reinstantiated?

Ive created some really basic example as a Showcase:

**View:**

```
<Window x:Class="View.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:View"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="300" Background="Black">
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding MainModelText}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    MainModel _MainModel;

    string _MainModelText;
    public string MainModelText
    {
        get { return this._MainModelText; }
        set
        {
            this._MainModelText = value;
            OnNotifyPropertyChanged("MainModelText");
        }
    }

    public ViewModel(MainModel mainModel)
    {
        this._MainModel = mainModel;
        this._MainModel.PropertyChanged += _MainModel_PropertyChanged;

    }

    private void _MainModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(string.Equals(e.PropertyName, "SomeText"))
        {
            this.MainModelText = _MainModel.SomeText + new Random().Next(1000);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnNotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if(this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class MainModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _SomeText;
    public string SomeText
    {
        get { return this._SomeText; }
        set
        {
            this._SomeText = value;
            OnNotifyPropertyChanged("SomeText");
        }
    }

    public MainModel()
    {
        this.SomeText = "Its MainModel!";
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnNotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

**Business-Logic**

```
public class Logic
{
    MainModel _MainModel;
    View.MainWindow _Window;

    public Logic()
    {
        this._MainModel = new MainModel();
        _Window = new View.MainWindow(new ViewModel(_MainModel));
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _Window.ShowDialog();
    }

    public void NewAll()
    {
        this._MainModel = new MainModel();
        //working...
        this._MainModel.SomeText = "Finished";
    }
}
```

So obviously "Finished" is not shown on the Window, since its set to another MainModel instance.

So how to update the Modelreference in the ViewModel?
Whats a Best Practice for something like this?

**EDIT:**

```
public class Logic
{
    MainModel _MainModel;
    ViewModel _ViewModel;
    View.MainWindow _Window;

    public Logic()
    {
        this._MainModel = new MainModel();
        this._ViewModel = new ViewModel(this._MainModel);
        _Window = new View.MainWindow(this._ViewModel);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _Window.ShowDialog();
    }

    public void NewAll()
    {
        this._MainModel = new MainModel();
        this._ViewModel.Reload(this._MainModel);
        //working...
        this._MainModel.SomeText = "Finished";
    }
}
```

Added in VM:

```
internal void Reload(MainModel mainModel)
{
    this._MainModel = mainModel;
    this._MainModel.PropertyChanged -= _MainModel_PropertyChanged;
    this._MainModel.PropertyChanged += _MainModel_PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: can't you just update model's properties instead of recreate the whole viewmodel?

Comment: Your viewmodel should have a public `Model` INPC property. When you give it a new `Model`, raise `PropertyChanged("Model")` in the setter. In the view, bind to `{Binding Model.SomeText}`.

Comment: And delete your `Logic` class. That has no role in any of this. Your main viewmodel "is the program". The MainWindow creates an instance of the main viewmodel in its constructor (or in XAML), and from there on in the main viewmodel is in charge. Main VM is in charge of the background process, which the main VM uses to update some of its own properties. Any other VMs are children of the main VM.

Comment: The `Logic` class is the main part of this, the View should just be some kind of userfriendly interaction (its also possible to interact via console). My understanding of this is, the VM is between Model and View and is controlling the View and is only responsible for this, nothing else, so the main Programm is the - what i called in this example - `Logic` class and is doing the main work. The VM --> View is just notified if a new execution starts to enable some user interactions. So the VM gets the new Model and shows something to the user if necessary - nothing more. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Please see edit. Its working, but dont know if this is a valid approach.

Comment: I won't argue. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a good reason for not providing your MainModel through a VM property I would recommend to do so. Then you can simply skip the SomeText property and bind to Model.SomeText directly since your Model already implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

If you want to load a completely new Model instance you can then set it on the VM property directly.

If you want to not provide the complete model to the view then your approach works. But I would call the ReloadModel also from the model constructor so you place the code at one place. Also you should unregister the PropertyChanged event from the oldModel not after you have already updated it to the new model (check for _mainModel == null first).

In your PropertyChanged call consider to use nameof(SomeProperty) instead of a fixed string "SomeProperty" like you do now. Then the code wont break if you would rename the property at some point.

Have a look at MVVM Light that framework would save you from writing some boilerplate code over and over again and the Messenger they provide is a good way to signal from Model to VM. It simplifies this sample to just a few lines.